# Problemas ao iniciar um Aplicativo com React Native

Tags: android, mobile, react-native, sdk

Estou usando o sistema operacional Deepin Linux.
Uso os seguintes comandos:

```
react-native init NomeDoProjeto

cd NomeDoProjeto
```

Ao executar o comando:

```
react-native run-android
```

Tenho o seguinte erro:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. What went wrong: A problem
>   occurred configuring project ':app'. The SDK directory
>   '/root/Android/Sdk' does not exist.

Mas meu diretório SDK existe nesta pasta. Eu uso o Genymotion e ele também está apontando para o mesmo SDK corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece quando a SDK não está sendo localizada pelo diretório fornecido. Tente criar/editar esse arquivo dentro do seu projeto: android/local.properties

Insira dentro dele

```
sdk.dir = diretório para sua sdk sem aspas
```

Tente rodar novamente