# react-native run android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Olá galera estou iniciando um projeto com react-native mas estou tendo sérios problemas até o momento em tentar rodar o código no emulador do android studio, até o momento ainda não fiz mudanças nos arquivos do projeto, estão do jeito que foram instalado. Se alguém puder me ajudar estarei grato, segue o erro :

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/eliascmendhes/my_pet/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/eliascmendhes/my_pet/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/eliascmendhes/my_pet/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (/home/eliascmendhes/my_pet/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (/home/eliascmendhes/my_pet/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problemas ao iniciar um Aplicativo com React Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298213/problemas-ao-iniciar-um-aplicativo-com-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo erro o sistema não está encontrando a SDK do android que contêm os Devices do emulador. Você deve configurar a variável de ambiente para que o react-native encontre o emulador corretamente.

Faça assim. Clique na busca do windows ou aperte a tecla Win do teclado. Pesquise Varíaveis de Ambiente. Você deve ver a seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique nesse botão de variáveis de ambiente e abaixo da lista de variáveis, clique em novo.
Em nome da varíavel digite

> ANDROID_HOME

Em valor da variável informe a pasta do SDK. Ela muda de acordo com a instalação mas geralmente fica em

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

e cole nesse campo de valor da variável e salve. 
RESSALVA: UserName no caminho geralmente é o seu nome de usuário do computador, e a pasta AppData geralmente fica oculta. Então é recomendável que você entre na pasta do SDK manualmente e copie o caminho completo.

Depois é só salvar e tentar compilar o projeto novamente.

Comment: Já fico muito agrado pela essa sua ajuda, mas eu uso o Ubuntu, e aí como fica ? Desde já obg.

Answer (score 1):

Na documentação oficial está escrito o seguinte para o linux. Execute depois que o Android SDK estiver instalado:

```
3. Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
The React Native tools require some environment variables to be set up in order to build apps with native code.

Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc config file:

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
.bash_profile is specific to bash. If you're using another shell, you will need to edit the appropriate shell-specific config file.

Type source $HOME/.bash_profile to load the config into your current shell. Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been added to your path by running echo $PATH.

Please make sure you use the correct Android SDK path. You can find the actual location of the SDK in the Android Studio "Preferences" dialog, under Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK.
```

Link: [Documentação Rect-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Caso você esteja utilizando o terminal zsh. Acesse o arquivo que está na sua pasta de usuário, o nome dele é .zshrc. Vá no final desse arquivo e adicione o seguinte código:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Caso você esteja com o terminal padrão do ubuntu, o bash, pode acessar o arquivo .bashrc na mesma pasta, e adicionar o mesmo código acima.

Após feito isso, basta fechar e abrir o terminal novamente, e vai funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

Entao carinha, passei pelos mesmos problemas à um tempo atras. A solucao que encontrei foi a seguinte. Depois de instalar a SDK voce precisa "avisar" no codigo nativo do android qual SDK ele deve usar.

1. Crie um arquivo `local.properties` na pasta do android.
2. Nesse arquivo passa o local aonde a SDK esta. Passa certo o local, comeca pela raiz. No meu Ubuntu ficou assim: `sdk.dir=/home/koe/Android/Sdk`
   Use a mesma sintaxe e passei o local certo.

Answer (score -2):

Você fez as instalações dos SDK's da maneira correta?

O erro ali aponta que você não está com o ambiente ANDROID configurado da maneira correta, você precisa definir as variáveis de ambiente após a instalação!

Caso você utilize o terminal padrão, você precisa ir até o arquivo: `~/.bashrc` e adicionar as seguintes linhas lá:

Caso utilize o ZSH, adicione as linhas no arquivo `~/.zshrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=CAMINHO_COM_A_VERSAO_DO_SEU_JDK
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Caso não saiba onde o seu JDK está instalado, pode rodar o seguinte comando no terminal:
`/usr/libexec/java_home` (não tenho certeza se este funciona em linux, estou num macOS)

ou `whereis java`

ou `echo $JAVA_HOME` se este funcionar, é para devolver exatamente o caminho do JDK.